# Looking for a method to set up a complete register/login system ,each user to have his own information

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

- I'm Using asp.net 4 .

My purpose is to make a login/register page for users.

- But there is something I need to take care : Each registered user
  should have his own gridview with his own information on his page
  after he logged in

Here's what I thought so far :

- Make a register page , on "submit"    button for creating the account
  , it will create a new table with the name of the user and the required
  columns.
- On the login page , I thought something like this : On user login
  redirect to general page and in the sqldatasource get the logged user
  name table and bind it to the gridview.

Is this a good idea?

Comment: You can use the standard Membership/ Role/ Profile ASP.NET models for this... not sure I'd want to "bind" it, per se, just map the values from the application services objects.

Comment: I'm not so advanced in asp.net would you please give me some examples? thank you

Comment: Is the schema for each user's table different? Creating tables for each user is not a good idea - creating a new row in an existing table is perfectly fine...Also, you should google "Membership provider" to help with some of this...

Comment: Well, I need to add a gridview on the asp page , and the registered user is adding his information in it so the information should be saved .

Answer (score 0):

I will only give you the flow assuming you know how to save and load data
Well what i do is make two tables one for user information and second table for User rights 
now when you register  user you dont use grid but lable with textboxs
and submit button for save logic 
now in admin page you show a grid and let the admin see all users in grid and use edit, inactive etc logic there
hope you find it useful

Comment: you missunderstood what I've asked